# Cloth simulation - Object won't touch obstacles

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to drop a piece of clothing onto various objects, but it won't touch them and remains hanging a couple of inches above. The repel setting is set to 0. Any ideas?

Comment: what about collision distance

Comment: Distance: 0.001, Repel distance: 0.001

Comment: what about other objects settings  " face thickness - outer "

Comment: Is the scale of objects applied? Not sure but it can help. BTW, please give us more details about your settings (add screenshots).

Comment: OMG, it was indeed the outer thickness set to 0.01 - which is the default I guess. It's working fine now, thanks guys for your help.  p.s. Just wondering if anyone else gets so utterly stuck on silly stuff like this.